# PostgreSQL increment age by one if matches previous column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as follows

```
    id    |    dob     |   date     
----------+------------+-----------
     1    | 22/09/2009 | 28/10/2014
     1    | 22/09/2009 | 25/11/2014
     1    | 22/09/2009 | 16/12/2014
     2    | 08/01/2010 | 30/09/2014
     2    | 08/01/2010 | 03/10/2014
```

I'm calculating the age in months by the following code in Postgres

```
SELECT id, ((EXTRACT(year FROM age(date,dob)) :: int) * 12) + (EXTRACT(month FROM age(date,dob))) FROM exmpleTable
```

And the result is as follows

```
    id    |    age          
----------+------------
     1    |     61 
     1    |     62 
     1    |     62 
     2    |     56
     2    |     56
```

The 'date' is unique per month. So 2 dates will not occur within the same month.
Now I need results as follows

```
    id    |    age          
----------+------------
     1    |     61 
     1    |     62 
     1    |     63 
     2    |     56
     2    |     57
```

Logic:

Either

1) If the calculated age is same as above, increment by one (I'm not sure how to use lag)

OR

2) Use maybe the end of month date from the same month as 'Date', which ensures the same age in months is not repeated

OR some other logic

Is there a way to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `lag()`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0203c5014a11de84a9bdc6f2c63aa502)**

```
with cte as 
(
SELECT id, ((EXTRACT(year FROM age(date,dob)) :: int) * 12) + (EXTRACT(month FROM age(date,dob))) as age FROM exmpleTable
)

select id, case when age=lag(age) over(order by id) then age+1 else age end as ageval
from cte
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  age
1   61
1   62
1   63
2   56
2   57
```

Comment: This logic worked. Never used lag before, seems really handy. Any idea how the other logic (using the end of the month date for calculation belonging to same month) would work?